# buck regulator MOSFET turning off for a short duratiopn

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I am designing a regulator system using a buck regulalator. The datasheet is - [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3845fd.pdf).

Now, the regulator can be configured to switch at 100-500kHz, and this is done using a resistor connected to the Fset pin. The schematic is as shown in the datasheet and is placed below as well -

[image: buck regulator].

I have configured my regulator to give 3.3V from an input of 10V at 300kHz.
Now, there is a weird behaviour happening. I am probing the TG pin of the IC, which basically controls the control mosfet or the higher MOSFET.

The scope data is as shown below -

[image: Scope waveform]

Now, the MOSFET is working fine or rather there is gate signal for a significant amount of time with the required frequency of 300kHz. But, then the gate goes low which disables the MOSFET.

I am unable to understand the reason why this is happening. Now, the Vc pi (error voltage) is a wave with voltage going from approx 0.75 to 1.23V. Is that notmal ?

Comment: You might want to correlate that with other pins, like those that are measuring Vout etc.

Comment: Are you loading the circuit ? If not a possible explanation is that it is operating in **burst mode** as pin BURST_EN is grounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the data sheet you linked to.  Page 11 explains burst mode.

The effect you are seeing is caused by the chip using burst mode.  When you are only drawing a low current from the chip, it will shut off the drive signal in order to save power.  At higher loads the drive signal runs continuously.

The sample circuit from the datasheet has burst mode enabled (BURST_EN grounded.)

---

In response to comment:
See page 11 of the datasheet, and see what it says about Vc.  Take a look at what Vc is doing.  Place a larger load on the output, and see that Vc rises.

Your load would seem to still qualify as "low load."  Given that the example circuit provides 75W of output, and yours (3.3V at .3A) gives only 1Watt, this seems reasonable.

Comment: I have placed a load and it is drawing almost 0.3Amps. So, it will not be an issue of burst mode.

Comment: How do you conclude that the chip will not enter burst mode when the load is 0.3 A ? Besides, burst mode could also be the result of too much reverse current.